# What does a "career move" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does a "career move" mean? 
Does it usually mean a change of job? 
Can it mean an action in the career?

Comment: [Career move](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/career-move)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the expression is used alone(not in a context) as in your question, it makes people think a **changing your existing job with a new one**.

Answer (score 1):

In this context move has two meanings: it is a transfer or change; and it is any sort of action that can be regarded as a strategic play, or possibly a misplay. It is

A career move is any sort of move related to one's career (a move of either type).

Examples:

> Telling sexual jokes was once commonplace in male-dominated workplaces, but today it is not a smart career move. [Nowadays, such behavior has bad consequences for your career, and it must be avoided.(move = strategic mistake; poor play)]
>
> Getting a master's degree or Ph. D. can be a good career move; it can open doors for you.[(move = strategic play)]
>
> The typical career move from what you're doing now would be to go into management, but I think you have what it takes to start your own business. [(move = change)]